# Replacing an cpu in a laptop

Tags: laptop, cpu, compatibility

My machine is Lenovo G580 with i3-3120M. I want to replace it with i5-3360M.

I checked on Intel's website that sockets are the same (PGA), TDP also the same (35 W) and BIOS works with both. I found info about motherboard and it is produced with both models.

Is this safe? And will heatsink work same good?

Comment: On some laptops the CPU is soldered onto the mainboard to save space...so, you might want to check that first.

Comment: Your CPU is soldered to your motherboard.  You won't be able to replace it.